# Spring Boot Docker Container can't connect to postgresql hosted on Docker host

Tags: postgresql, maven, docker, spring-boot

when I use maven to build my spring boot app the application needs to have a connection to my postgresql database in the application.properties. It only can connect when I use

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
```

but when I containerize the buileded jar file, my application can't connect to my postgres database hosted outside the Container.

what is the solution for this problem?

I am still a Beginner

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: yes i am using Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

From the 18.03 docs:

> I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host.
>
> The gateway is also reachable as gateway.docker.internal.

example:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/springbootdb`

Comment: The information above can be found in the Networking documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Answer (score 1):

Where you hosted your PostgreSQL database?

Replace localhost with actual machine IP address (PostgreSQL database machine address)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:<ip_address>:5432/springbootdb
```

Comment: didnt work for me: 
java.net.UnknownHostException: postgresql 
when I want to build with maven

Comment: Where is your PostgreSQL database? on same machine where docker installed? or outside? (windows?) and where is docker application (windows/ubuntu?)

Comment: it's on my windows localhost, but i think the Container has another Environment. same machine as docker right

Comment: is your firewall blocking incoming/outgoing port 5432? can you please add/allow both in and out 5432 on your windows firewall?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me, thank you for your advices